# Golang Singleton for all replicas of microservice

Tags: go, kubernetes, microservices

I am using sync.once to implement singleton in my microservice. But I am not sure if this will ensure a single instance for all the replicas.
How to create a Singleton object for distributed microservices in golang?

Answer (score 4):

It cannot ensure a single instance between multiple processes running in different environments. `sync` is used to synchronise go routines, which are running against the main routine process.

To add locking that would work between multiple processes and multiple microservices, you need a single third-party instance, that would control it. It can be a queue message / cache broker (e.g. [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [Redis](https://redis.io/)) or database (e.g. [PostgreSQL advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS)).